# Matching groups with equals means and proportions

Tags: r, random, matching, knapsack-problem

Given the following data

```
set.seed(123)
id  <- data.frame(id=seq(1:100))
df <- data.frame(id,
                   lef=(sample(27:65,nrow(id), replace = TRUE)),
                 tra=(sample(1:5,nrow(id), replace = TRUE)),
             ab=(sample(c("A", "B"),nrow(id), replace = TRUE)),
                zxc=(sample(c("Z", "X", "C"),nrow(id), replace = TRUE)))
```

I want a (random?) selection out of df that leads to:

1. 4 groups with a size of exact 10 each (Group 1 n=10; G2 n=10 ….)
2. Replacement is not allowed (unique id within and between the groups)
3. the 4 groups must contain all the columns (G1= 5x10; G2 = 5X10…..)
4. the 4 groups “must” have equal means on ‘lef’ (meanG1=meanG2=…)and equal
   proportions on ‘ab’ (Pa1=Pa2…; Pb1=Pb2….), ‘tra’ and ‘zxc’, or
   result in the most optimal solution given df.

I have looked over the internet but could not find a solution, this could be a problem using incorrect keys (knapsack, matching algorithm).

Comment: @halfer, thank you for the edit, do you have a hint on how to solve the problem?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, often editors will _just_ edit, so there isn't much value in chasing an individual editor for an answer. I wonder, looking at it, whether it is a bit broad. I don't use R, but it seems to me that the code you have supplied generates your data, and then you wish to run an algorithm on it. Can you try writing that algorithm yourself? What are you stuck on in particular? We also have a close reason of "request for third-party resources", and I wonder if this would qualify.